# react native maps convert coordinates to address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to include the react native maps components into my app. So far so good, the map is already included and when I click the map the console displays the coordinates in my terminal. My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'; 

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const MapScreen = props =>{
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView 
                style={styles.map}
                zoomEnabled = {true}
                maxZoomLevel={10}
                rotateEnabled={false}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                onPress={e => 
                    console.log(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)
                }
                
            >

            </MapView>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        width:"100%", 
        height:"100%",
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    map:{
        width: "95%",
        height: "95%"
    }
});

export default MapScreen;
```

and when I click on the map I get for example a return like this object:

> Object {   "latitude": 17.85559294697312,   "longitude":
> 14.705276302993298, }

This is totaly fine and its working without a problem but I now I want to make it better: **I want to transform this coordinates into an adress-type object with the following method:** [image]

[Those methods can be found here.](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods)

The only problem is: I dont know how. The documentation has no example of a code which used one of any of those methods listened there and Im struggling hard to pull this idea off and I would need some help here definetly.

Comment: What's the problem ? Just import it and pass your coordinate object to this aync method: addressForCoordinate(myCoordinates).then(address => console.log(address))

Comment: @BloodyMonkey do you have a solution for this? According to https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3775 it's not yet implemented.

Comment: Do you use expo managed workflow ?

Comment: Yes I use the managed workflow but I will need to soon eject it anyways because I want to include payment options into my app. Maybe then I can try this one out again.